# Как убрать кнопку назад в actionBar в конкретном фрагменте android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

У меня есть **два главных фрагмента** от которых можно переходить к **другим фрагментам**. Как мне во **втором главном фрагменте** убрать кнопку назад в actionBar.

Код:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это, по идее, зависит от того, как эта кнопка назад в тулбаре появилась. Предположу, что вы гугловую навигацию используете. Коли так - то у вас, по идее, где-то должен быть код привязки тулбара к гугловой навигации. В теории, если этот код удалить - то и кнопка пропадёт. Могу ещё пару десятков вариантов описать, но не вижу смысла пока вы не покажете код)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил код

Comment: В приведённом коде не видно использования тулбара. Как он у вас сделан? Вы его указываете в разметке или он через стили задан? В любом случае, где-то выше по иерархии экранов должен быть, по идее, код его настройки. Покажите код экрана, где находится контейнер для навигации (это, наверное, ваша MainActivity)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил

Comment: Судя по всему вот тут нужный вам ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463839/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за помощь!!!